# Firebase-cloud-messaging docs use of *foreground* and *background* confusing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-lifecycle

## Problem

I've found that FirebaseMessagingService's onMessageReceived is called when the app is running, i.e. after a onResume, onPause and onStop lifecycle event. The message is only automatically delivered to the notification tray if the app has been killed.

Is this the expected behaviour?

According to the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), a notification message should trigger a notification in the system tray when the app is in the *background*. A notification message should be delivered to the onMessageReceived function when the app is in the *foreground*.

I expected *foreground* to imply that the app is currently active (i.e. just after the onResume method) and *background* to imply that the app is currently inactive (after onPause or onStop). This would be consistent with the way *foreground* and *background* is used in the Android docs.

## Reproduce

I build a clean Android application and integrate Firebase-Cloud-Messaging. I then have three java files:

[image: Android Files]

MainActivity.java only logs activity lifecycle events:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity OnCreate");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (refreshedToken != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "Activity onStop");
    }
}
```

And MyFirebaseMessagingService handles notification messages received in the foreground

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MessagingService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

In logcat

- After onResume, onMessageReceived receives the message
  [image: Logcat onResume]
- After onPause and onStop, onMessageReceived still receives the message
  [image: Logcat onStop]
- When I kill the app, I successfully receive the notification in the notification tray